# Retrieving values from SQLite table iOS

Tags: ios, fmdb, select-query, ios-sqlite

As I'm new to iOS programming,I have a doubt in retrieving data corresponding to a particular integer id from  `SQLite` database table?

This is what I tried but seems wrong:

```
NSInteger id=  sender.tag;
FMResultSet *rs = [self.databaseFM executeQuery:@"select * from tblVenue where venue_id = ?",id];
```

Is the problem related to Integer typecasting?

Comment: what are you using instead of "venue_id = ?" ?

Comment: it's showing any error ?. what is FMResultSet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `-numberWithInteger:` like this :-

```
NSInteger id=  sender.tag;
FMResultSet *rs = [self.databaseFM executeQuery:@"select * from tblVenue where venue_id = ?", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:id]];
```